# Prove the equation with binomial sum

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Prove: $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}{{\alpha+k}\choose k}={{\alpha+n+1}\choose n},\alpha\in\mathbb{R},k\in\mathbb{N}$

$${{\alpha+n+1}\choose n}=\frac{(\alpha+n+1)!}{n!(\alpha+1)!}$$

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}{{\alpha+k}\choose k}=\frac{n!\alpha !+n!\alpha !(\alpha+1)+\frac{n!}{2}(\alpha+2)!+...+(n-1)!(\alpha+n)!}{n!\alpha !}$$

How to transform the sum to get the equation?

Comment: That is straightforward to prove by induction on $n$.

Comment: How $(\alpha +k )! $  is defined with  $\alpha  \in \mathbb{R}$  ??

Comment: $\alpha$ seems to be a real number. How would you define $\alpha !$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom {\alpha+k}k&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom {\alpha+k}\alpha\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom {\alpha+k+1}{\alpha+1}-\binom {\alpha+k}{\alpha+1}\\
&=\binom {\alpha+n+1}{\alpha+1}\\
&=\binom {\alpha+n+1}n\quad\blacksquare\end{align}$$